# Free/libre WLAN router

Tags: router, wlan, floss

I’m looking for a WLAN router that runs only free/libre software. It doesn’t need to contain a modem.

ThinkPenguin.com offered the [Free Software Wireless-N Broadband Router for GNU / Linux (TPE-NWIFIROUTER2)](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/free-software-wireless-n-broadband-router-gnu-linux-tpe-nwifirouter2), which even got [FSF’s RYF certification](http://www.fsf.org/resources/hw/endorsement/respects-your-freedom), but it’s "no longer for sale/available".

I would prefer a router that ships without any proprietary software, but if there isn’t one, I’m fine with a router that ships with proprietary software, as long as a free/libre OS (and free/libre firmware) can be installed without voiding the warranty, ideally officially supported.

Comment: Do you have any requirements beyond "free/libre", eg. wireless protocols, or number/speed of Ethernet ports?

Comment: @Mark: As I don’t know what wireless protocols are, I guess … no? Or has this to do with the encryption? WPA2 support would be nice, but I guess this should be standard. No requirements regarding speed or ethernet ports.

Comment: Wireless protocols: 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac and so on.

Comment: @Mark: I don’t know enough to decide if it matters or which one I would need.

Comment: @unor they're in increasing order of bandwidth, effectively. 802.11ac is the best; 802.11a carries little. AC-supporting devices are relatively new and expensive - you're more likely to find N-supporting devices.

Answer (score 3):

Minifree offers the [**Libre WNDR3800 Router**](https://minifree.org/product/minifree-wndr3800-libre-router/).

These are refurbished Netgear WNDR3800 or WNDR3800-1CHNAS routers that come pre-installed with free software only (uboot, [libreCMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LibreCMC)).

While it has no RYF certification as of 2019-01-08, Minifree submitted the router for approval:

> It’s a completely FSF-endorseable router: in fact, Minifree has sent the FSF a router for [RYF evaluation](https://www.fsf.org/resources/hw/endorsement/respects-your-freedom). We are confident that this will succeed, and our laptops are already endorsed.

---

Vikings offers the same: **[Vikings WNDR3800 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router](https://store.vikings.net/libre-friendly-hardware/wndrrouter)**